# Many-to-many relations are dropped when updating a foreign entity in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, many-to-many, propel

I'm working with Symfony 1.2 (can't update, it's not up to me) with Propel as ORM. I'm having a bizarre problem with my many-to-many relations.

Let's say you have two tables `A` and `B`, and a many-to-many relation `A_has_B`. Let's say I have an `a` entity in `A`, a `b` entity in `B`, and a relation in `A_has_B` which PK is `(a_id, b_id)`. Now, if I update `b` entity (not its id, but another field which is not its PK) using symfony admin generated modules, then `(a_id, b_id)` is dropped from the database.

This only happens using Symfony backend. It DOESN'T happen using phpmyadmin, where I can update `a` and `b` without loosing `(a_id, b_id)` relation.

All tables are MySQL/InnoDB. Columns `A_id` and `B_id` in `A_has_B` are foreign keys pointing to `A` and `B` id's. I have `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in both columns.

Thank you very much for your help.

**UPDATE:** Here is the yml schema, for three tables `Team` and `Participants` and its relation

```
propel:
  _attributes:
    package: lib.model
    defaultIdMethod: native
  team:
    _attributes: { phpName: Team }
    id: { type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
    name: { type: VARCHAR, size: '255', required: true }
    description: { type: LONGVARCHAR, required: false }
  participant:
    _attributes: { phpName: Participant }
    id: { type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
    name: { type: VARCHAR, size: '255', required: true }
  team_has_participant:
    _attributes: { phpName: TeamHasParticipant }
    team_id: { type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, required: true, foreignTable: team, foreignReference: id, onDelete: CASCADE, onUpdate: CASCADE }
    participant_id: { type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, required: true, foreignTable: participant, foreignReference: id, onDelete: CASCADE, onUpdate: CASCADE }
    _indexes: { participant_id: [participant_id] }
```

Say I update `description` field in a `team` entity, then I'm loosing all the `team_has_participant` relations that had that foreign `team` entity.

Comment: can you post you yml or xml schema?

Comment: @Vlad Nedelcu, schema updated to the question

Comment: i don't see the problem. If you update the `b` entity's id, the link table entry is no longer valid. That is how its suposed to work.

Comment: But I'm not updating `b` entitity's id, I'm updating another field which is not its PK, so the entity is the same and the link table shouldn't be dropped (as it's happening using phpmyadmin instead of symfony backend)

Comment: i think its an issue of phpMyAdmin. If you tag the question  with `php` and `phpMyAdmin` probably expert people could help you. Good luck

Comment: It can't be. phpmyadmin is doing well. It's a problem with symfony, php or mysql. Thank you @Andreu Heineken

Comment: Can I know why that negative votes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized what the problem was. Of course, something silly.

In my relations, say `A_has_B` I was hidding the `a_has_b_list` field in `B` generator.yml to only allow modifications from `A` form. But it's a mistake, because just hidding the field in generator.yml doesn't unset it, just hidde it and it is posted with a blank value (so it overrides the database). It's necessary to unset the widget in `B` form `configure()` method:

```
unset($this->widgetSchema['a_has_b_list'];
```

This way, nothing is posted and database is not overriden.